# Image not loading in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, game-development

So I have tried multiple things(Firstly the code was OOP based but i changed it, messed around with variable but it was of no use) and I dont know why my image (Hero.png in code) isn't showing.I'm kinda new to python/pygame so it must be a dumb mistake. Thanks anyways here is the code.It isnt a complete code yet.

```
Import pygame
pygame.init()

winX = 720
winY = 1280
win = pygame.display.set_mode([winY, winX])
GameRun = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
HeroSprite = pygame.image.load('Hero.png')
pygame.display.set_caption("Game thingy")
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
HeroX = winX / 2
HeroY = winY - 100
vel = 5
def redrawGameWindow(win, HeroX,HeroY):
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))
    win.blit(HeroSprite, (HeroX, HeroY))
    pygame.display.update()

while GameRun:
    clock.tick(60)
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        HeroX -= vel if HeroX > 20 else 0
    elif pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        HeroX += vel if HeroX < winX - 20 else 0

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            GameRun = False
    redrawGameWindow(win, HeroX, HeroY)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Do you get some kind of error message? If so, please include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've swapped `winX` and `winY`:

> ```py
> winX = 720
> winY = 1280
> win = pygame.display.set_mode([winY, winX])
> ```

So the initial position of the hero is not in the window:

> ```py
> HeroX = winX / 2
> HeroY = winY - 100
> ```

Swap the variables for the size of the window:

```py
winX = 1280
winY = 720
win = pygame.display.set_mode([winX, winY])
```